# Can't overprint colors on inkjet printer

Tags: printing

I have two separate files, first with black line, second with blue line.

This is how I intend to print. First I print the black line then I load paper into printer again and print over it with blue.

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
[image]

However, when I look on the paper I am getting results like this with black line being on top of the blue.

[image]

Is this problem because of particular type of printer e.g. ink-jet?

Comment: Maybe wait for the ink to cure before trying to overprint.

Comment: some software (such as Adobe InDesign) allows for *knockout* and *trapping*. If you have 2 properly registered files (or "plates") you are manually compositing, then maybe the software which created the two files/plates can handle knockout.

Comment: Would it not be easier to edit the two files together with the blue file layered on top of the black file? This way, you'd actually have blue over black (i.e. no black at all where they cross), and it would tell the printer to print blue there. You'd also have the added bonus of printing one time instead of twice and the associated headaches of misalignment (where the paper doesn't feed through the printer exactly the same on the 2 prints so they colors come out in the wrong place).

Comment: I guess it depends if the blue ink _reflects_ blue light, or just _transmits_ (passes through / does not absorb) blue light.  In the latter case, the blue would come from the whiteness of the paper behind (which you've diminished with black ink).  I suppose there could plausibly be a kind of ink that *reflects* blue light, but I doubt it because then we'd probably have access to white ink that could print on black paper.  I believe inkjet inks are subtractive/transmissive, not reflective.

Comment: Would it be OK if Comments and Answers clearly distinguished between printing one image over another, as in the OQ, and capabilities such as knockout and trapping which are vital in other circumstances, but have no say here?

I'm asking everyone to remember that when printing a fresh image on already-used paper, as in the OQ, what matters most and prolly over-rides all else is the darkness of the inks.

Most obviously, you can print black over white but white over black requires a sophisticated commercial press, not a desk-top printer.

Answer (score 31):

This is mostly an artifact of how the light behaves in regard to pigments and much less related to the particular printing technology.

If you mix a good black ink with a comparable amount of whatever other ink, you will get black ink.

The reason is simple:

While the blue ink absorbs some of the light, but allows the constituents of the blue color to pass or reflect, the black is expected to absorb all of the visible light.

Mixing the inks, you are summing their absorptive capabilities.

If you add a very tiny amount of black to the blue, you can get some tone of dark blue.

If you mix some other colors (e.g. magenta and yellow inks) either on paper or in a liquid form, you will get some composite color (e.g. red with the proper amount of magenta and yellow).

In fact, this is how the printer creates its diverse color palette with just 4 basic colors. In theory, one could go with even only 3 inks - magenta, yellow and cyan, but black is added to improve the contrast because the other 3 are not perfect light filters (black is usually really good). Black is also used for printing black and white images because it is also cheaper.

---

p.s. contrast this when you paint some high-opacity paint over an already dried out different paint.

In this case, paints don't mix (or at least are not expected to mix) and it is the paint who reflects the light (and not the substrate under the paint like it happens in printing).

One can get whatever new color wants by just covering the old paint with the new one.

Maybe this is what you expect in your exercise, but printing works differently from painting.

Comment: If this answer is correct, which I think it is (+1), it is easy enough to test. Print blue then black or black then blue and the result should be black. Same with black and any other color. On the other hand, if the other answer is correct then the sequence will make a big difference.

Comment: I faintly remember some inkjet printer drivers having an "overprint" option which would cause the driver to avoid placing black ink where another non-black color would need to be printed on top.

Comment: It does depend on the printing technology. E.g. with [solid ink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_ink) printers, an effect as wanted could probably be created.

Comment: @user1686 wouldn't that be the same as just setting those pixels to white before printing?

Comment: @user253751: Technically it would, but is that something you want to spend time doing manually every time if the driver can do it instead? (I can't remember if it's a driver option or an Adobe software option though.)

Comment: @user1686 you'd have to find the option in the driver and tell it where the overprinting was going to be!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact marker pen rather than paint - paint is more opaque and less like inkjet ink

Answer (score 25):

**You cannot overprint with ink-jet printers.**
You can only do what you want using a laser printer.

With ink-jet printers, the color is a dye that is absorbed into the paper. A second pass of printing will blend the new print into the existing dyed paper. When you print blue over yellow you will notice that it might turn green.

With laser printers, the "ink" is actually "toner" which is placed *on top of the paper* and then fused in place using heat. Whether that toner is carbon, or wax, or other materials - this does not matter. What matters is that the print is a layer **on** the paper, not **in** the paper. And a second print on the same paper can place a new layer on top. The final result depends on the opacity of the toner.

Comment: Note that this also gives you the option of printing on paper that isn't white (or light colored) to begin with.  e.g.: If you wanted to print something on a black background, it's far more economical to start with paper that's already black and add the colors on top of that.  This is of course impossible to do with an ink-jet.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Not the option of printing white text on black background.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Some higher end specialty printers can do that, but yeah, not the average ones.

Comment: Blue (which is cyan + magenta) over yellow will turn black, not green.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume this is a conceptual drawing rather than an actual picture of the results, because it doesn't look like what I see when I examine inkjet prints.

Inkjet sprays the ink on the paper with some control of droplet size to correspond with density of the color being sprayed.  As such, it may not actually get complete coverage, and an oversprayed ink may not cover completely what is under it.  Also, the ink may be somewhat transparent, especially the colored rather than black.  If the ink is not completely dry, there may also be mixing of the oversprayed ink droplets into the underneath layer or into the paper.  Also, typically inkjet ink is water soluble, so the second layer of ink may actually reactivate and mix into the first layer even if it was completely dry.

All of these factors together likely result in what you are seeing, and a microscopic photo may clear up which of these factors is dominant.